# BigQuery interactive query response times degradation since 2/19/16

Tags: google-bigquery

For the Google BigQuery infrastructure folks: we've been running a set of short running interactive queries for many months now averaging about 5 seconds to complete. Starting Friday 2/19 these response times have been rising steadily (SQL has not changed and we're dealing with a steady stream of data we're querying using a sliding window)

[image]

Is this a global BigQuery issue you are aware of?

edit: more granular response times:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a job id of a job that took longer than expected to run. There are no global bigquery issues that we know of. (ideally, if you could also provide a job id of a job that ran quickly, that would be helpful too)

Comment: Here's a short (relatively) short one: SOobGfn97JIaLKyeeu5tDFgT4G3maBgs26xO3fm0Xp2wDMFjy7yJFryFCWQkTOEI96mWFij1ZSbj4d7gOKByCb1cB8ZLqdZcfPG8rZh5QSCYGLaqBLKhyI0weIL0YkenbKHYKRYYQRfoiLVHGuG9oBDfn8VprJH61aC0AcbLeL_xZmyX8UXtio0gMjNnY4BFsxpEHbKHyJyxW984grv1NedH94krsC3d1_esrPIKz5c58L5MZzQn4iq9VL3VjOQz  (25 secs) and a long one j2JaIDT9yw3bjI3MskbidDnSdKeZX4KM_IXYPY34_iWQogzSvYjT5U9NxAy8EakTIsLp6ODW0pkevmcVNTaVvGoDZb9GlEIEK0LOlJEyp103Y3nrHIwWFW7b5CzqMs9UVkGa3PTXIIeWY136mJiyeI29yuhFkvZumDNjQ2LBeFezAb1jcKlEAf6WiV7GaWVpqeP8_PgVFv2sHfL0RC9wyJe9dXg98osJ5PmWSDge5VdXbwsAb5LV04M1b6JlQA7h (3 min, 13 secs).

Comment: Both of the above processed about 2.7 MB. We kick off around 19K of these a day (over the day) and been sort of relying on these completing in ~ 5 secs. These get funneled in a 40/s App Engine queue to stay within the 50/s running query limit. With these increases, the queues fill up and delays start to occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is good news and bad news; the good news is that the query took only 0.5 seconds to execute. The bad news is that it took 191 seconds to find the files where the data was stored.

We have a couple of performance regressions that cause high tail latency for resolving paths. Tables (like yours) where the data is stored in many paths will see worse performance.

This is performance issue is  exacerbated by the fact that you're using time-range decorators, which mean that our efforts to optimize the file layout doesn't work as well.

We are starting the roll-out of a fix to the underlying performance problem this afternoon; it will likely take at least a week for it to take effect everywhere. I'll update this answer once it is complete (if I forget, please remind me)

In the mean time, you may get faster results by removing the time-range decorators from your queries. You are already filtering by time, so the queries should still be correct. Of course, this may mean that the queries cost a bit more to run.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Jordan, I will take out the decorators until you give the green light.

Comment: Response times are back in the 4 - 5 sec range for us since 1:30 AM EST.

Comment: Jordan: One question on your comment as to our tables having data stored in many paths: is this referring to the TABLE_QUERY usage, unions or left outer joins?

Comment: This is due to how bigquery tables are stored internally. If you do a lot of small imports, those will get individually put into separate files until they're later optimized (and streaming imports also generate small files). If you use time-range decorators, this means we can't use the optimized versions. But TABLE_QUERY may also end up reading a lot of small tables, so you'd get the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, yes these tables are all populated by streaming imports.